# JQuery Server Side Processing and Columns Populating - MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am currently trying to populate my DataTable inside a View using a Serverside request however I am having some trouble populating my table columns with the resulting JSON.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "filter": false,
        'aoColumnDefs': [{
            'bSortable': false,
            'aTargets': ['nosort']
        }],
        "orderMulti": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "LoadLogData",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json",
            "dataSrc": function (json) {

                console.log(json);

                if(json.data[0].Date_Time!=null){

                var dt = json.data[0].Date_Time;

        for ( var i=0, ien=json.data.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
            json.data[i].Date_Time = dtConvFromJSON(json.data[i].Date_Time);
            json.data[i].Timestamp = dtConvFromJSON(json.data[i].Timestamp);
        }
                    }
        return json.data;
    }
        },
        "columns": [
           { "data": "MachineID", "name": "MachineID", autoWidth: true },
             { "data": "Date_Time", "name": "Date_Time", autoWidth: true },
                  { "data": "Timestamp", "name": "Timestamp", autoWidth: true }
        ]
    })
     });
</script>
```

My doubt is how to make column specification non-static. I don't want to specify that there is column named "MachineID", "Date_Time" and "Timestamp"
Is this even possible?

Comment: To my knowledge, this can be simplified to just `"columns": [[ "title": "MachineID" ], ["title": "Date_Time"]` etc. You can certainly store the title information server side and then loop over them, or just name the headers in the `html`. What do you mean by "non-static?"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem partialy with the following code

```
  "columns": [

             @{ var cont = 0;}
               @foreach (string varname in (List<string>)Session["LogTableVariables"])
    {
        @:{"data": "VariableValues", "name": "@varname", autoWidth:true},

                   cont++;
               }]
```

However now I get for Example

Column1 | Column2

1,2---------1,2

When I should be getting

Column1 | Column2

1-------------2